# ImageMagick: combine two images with transparency at the border

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, combine

I have two JPGs one `big.jpg` and the other `small.jpg`.
I want to extract a region `region.jpg` of `big.jpg` of the same size as `small.jpg` and merge `region.jpg` and `small.jpg` into a `result.jpg`. `result.jpg` is equal to `small.jpg`, except at the 16 pixels boundary where it gets more and more similar to `region.jpg`.

Using ImageMagick, I have done this in two steps, making a semitransparent PNG first:

```
convert -compress None small.jpg -channel A -virtual-pixel transparent -morphology Distance Euclidean:4,16! semitransparent.png
convert -compress None big.jpg -crop wxh+x+y semitransparent.png -composite result.jpg
```

Is there any way of doing this in a single step, without generating the intermediate PNG? I tried this:

```
convert -compress None big.jpg -crop wxh+x+y small.jpg -channel A -virtual-pixel transparent -morphology Distance Euclidean:4,16! -composite result.jpg
```

But this is not quite the same: the semitransparent layer does not end up really transparent at the edge.

I am a total newbie to ImageMagick (what a complex piece of software!), any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I'm adding files `big.jpg` and `small.jpg` to play with, together with `result.jpg` that comes out of the 2-line solution, and `result2.jpg` that comes out of the oneliner. The `-crop` I used was `200x160+160+80`:

[image: big.jpg] big.jpg

[image: small.jpg] small.jpg

[image: result.jpg] result.jpg (2 line solution)

[image: result2.jpg] result2.jpg (oneliner)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I just found the answer. Simply add `-compose atop` before the `-composite`:

```
convert -compress None big.jpg -crop 200x160+160+80 small.jpg \
  -channel A -virtual-pixel transparent \
  -morphology Distance Euclidean:4,16! \
  -compose atop -composite result.jpg
```